# t-student or f-distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, t-distribution, f-distribution

I am reading 'Applied multivariate statistical analysis' by Richard Johnson and I do not understand that first to explain this test, talks about the t-student distribution.

[image]

And then out of nowhere he plugs the f-distribution:
[image]

I even read this post: [Relationship between F and Student's t distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160559/relationship-between-f-and-students-t-distributions)

But, i am not able to follow the explanation. Why has he plugging the f-distribution out of nowhere? and if the result is a mix of t and f distributions, why isn't this a complete new distribution with a different name? (I would like to be able to understand this graphically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the second part is for *multivariate analysis* in $p$ dimensions, unlike the first screenshot which deals with all scalars. It proceeds with an analogy from univariate case. In multivariate case, you won't be able to compare a statistics of the form $T=n(\bar{X}-\mu_0)S^{-1}$ against a threshold because it is $p$ dimensional. However, by analogy, the univariate case is generalized to multivariate case, i.e. $$t^2=\frac{(\bar X-\mu_0)^2}{S/\sqrt{n}}=n(\bar X-\mu_0)\frac{1}{S}(\bar X-\mu_0)\rightarrow T^2=n\mathbf{(\bar X -\mu_0)^TS^{-1}(\bar X - \mu_0)}$$
And, the statistics obtained, i.e. $T^2$ is a scalar which we can compare against a threshold. Its distribution is [Hotelling's T-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution).